# protractor angularjs end to end testing

Tags: angularjs, carousel, protractor

How so I write test cases for carousel image slider in protractor. i.e. check if image is sliding automatically or on click of prev and next button check image should change.

Comment: what have you tried? please include some code examples so we have something to work from when helping you.

Comment: element = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//div[@class='carousel slide']//span"));
element.click(); for(int i=0;i<2;i++);{
        Thread.sleep(500);
        element.click(); i was trying to find the element but i dont know how the click event will fire as the same is in <span class="ng-scope">></span> and how can i assert if the image/text has been changed

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would want to have locators for previous and next buttons and for the active image e.g.:

```
var prev = element(by.css('.prev')); 
var next = element(by.css('.next'));
var activeImage = element(by.css('img.active'));
```

You could then test button clicks for a series of 2 images e.g.

```
var beforeImage = "apples.jpg";
var afterImage = "pears.jpg";

it('apples followed by pears', function() {
    expect(activeImage.getAttribute('src')).toBe(beforeImage);
    next.click();
    expect(activeImage.getAttribute('src')).toBe(afterImage );
});

it('pears followed by apples', function() {
    next.click();
    expect(activeImage.getAttribute('src')).toBe(afterImage );
    prev.click();
    expect(activeImage.getAttribute('src')).toBe(beforeImage);
```

})

Comment: I have a similar situation. But that previous and after buttons appear according to data. I have some overRideGUid for which data could be anywhere from 7 yrs to just 2 months. So that arrow is not constant or limited to just 2 or 10. How do i automate this?